# Java, Replenishing Iterator or Queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a project that involves many threads. I have a manager class that contains a list of models which my threads use for computation etc. This is a basic synchronized array list containing a couple items. Now I want each of my threads to take a different item, an item that currently isn't being used, similar to a queue. Using foreach isn't a possibility since I have more items and than threads. 1:20 ratio. Using a queue would also be possible but I want it to replenish and I don't know if that is the best way or not.

My question is: How do I tackle this problem. Some have already suggested using a synchronized iterator but that doesn't work with multiple threads...

EDIT: The items don't change. I just don't want threads using the same item at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is what you are looking for. Multiple threads can safely add and remove, and you don't need to iterate over it, you can just poll the head of the queue for new items, and you can put (offer) new items into the queue. This is slightly different than the BlockingQueue that @AdrianPang described since threads here will return immediately (with null) if nothing is in the queue. The exact collection you need depends on the behavior you want, but using a concurrent queue of one type or another here seems like a fit.

Comment: Offering the same 2000 items each time seems a bit to sluggish in my opinion.

Comment: I see, I didn't know they were the same items.

Comment: Should have noted that.

Comment: But, you could take it off the queue and just offer it back on when you're done. The take/offer shouldn't be your bottleneck, and you should actually verify that before saying it's "sluggish", other solutions will still involve some synchronization to determine which item the thread should take off the queue.

Comment: Now that you mention the take/offer, that's brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

What you described sounds like a use case for [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) Your threads will be calling take() on the queue (and block until one is available) and your main thread can supply model objects (by calling offer)